# Beautiful Soup strangely returning '/photo-missing.png'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to automate the downloading of player images from the www.premierleague.com website. The issue I am now facing is that when I use BeautifulSoup to parse the img src of the player photos, it is returning "photo-missing.png".

[image: de_gea]

You can see when you inspect the [html](https://www.premierleague.com/players/4330/David-De-Gea/overview) it is called  p51490.png !? and not "photo-missing.png"

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

player_page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/players/4330/David-De-Gea/overview')
soup = BeautifulSoup(player_page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(class_="imgContainer"))
```

The output of this yields:

```
 <div class="imgContainer"><img alt="David De Gea" class="img" data- 
    player="p51940" data-script="pl_player-image" data-size="250x250" data- 
    widget="player-image" src="//platform-static- 
    files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/Photo- 
    Missing.png"/></div>
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generated automatically by JS, maybe to prevent scraping. but you can just replace `Photo-Missing` with  `p51490`, this value saved in `data-player` attribute.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(player_page.text, 'html.parser')
# using CSS selector
img = soup.select_one('.imgContainer img')
img['src'] = img['src'].replace('Photo-Missing', img['data-player'])
print(img)
print(img['src'])
```